# ReferenceError: function not defined. Method calling other methods within a class

Tags: javascript, class, methods, referenceerror

I am having an issue calling a method within a class I have instantiated.  I have a class with methods which I call in the order I want in one method in the bottom of the class, this may be my issue.  All I do is instantiate the class then call the one method that has the other methods inside of it.  I am getting a function not defined error for the first method I call.  Thank you for any help.

Below is my code, I am only showing the method not defined "sortTimestamp" and the main method where all the other methods are called.

There are more variable declarations in the constructor I withheld for space concerns.

```
class sortedGroups{
    constructor(testArray){
        this.testArray = testArray;

sortTimestamp(){
    indexOfOldestGroup = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < this.testArray.length; i++){
        if(this.testArray[i][11] > this.oldestGroup[0][11]){
            this.oldestGroup.length = 0;
            this.oldestGroup.push(this.testArray[i]);
            indexOfOldestGroup = i;
        }
    }
    return indexOfOldestGroup;
}


ultimateCombiner = function (){

    let indexOfOldestGroup = sortTimestamp();

    removeGroupSearching(indexOfOldestGroup);

    sortGroupsByNeeds();

    let closestFive = findListOf5Closest();

    let groupToBeDeleted = combine(closestFive);

    deletesMatchedGroup(groupToBeDeleted);
    }
}

let firstSort = new sortedGroups(testArray);

firstSort.ultimateCombiner();
```

UPDATE: I now realize my problem is calling my methods from another method within the same class.  However if I use the same logic outside of my class the many variables I create/update in my class will not be updated.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please format the code a bit and add the class declaration in it ?

Answer (score 0):

I simply added this.function and fixed my errors, sorry for the misguided and simple question.  Thank you.